# If statement directly in class declaration

Tags: ruby

How come in Ruby it's possible to directly have an if statement directly in the class declaration? AKA:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  if foo
    bar = "x"
  end
end
```

I know there is some class instance variables, since the Class inherits from Object, is it the same thing?

I just need some clarification about this whole thing :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body of a class declaration is code just like everything else in Ruby. That's how you can use methods like `attr_accessor`, `private` and `include` — those are all just methods of the class. It's part of Ruby's philosophy of pervasive object orientation.

Comment: All good answers, I give it to you because I just saw your answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344797/ruby-method-calls-declared-in-class-body and it also helped! Thanks

Comment: @allaire: Nice! I thought I remembered that answer and was looking to link it, but I couldn't track it down at the time.

Answer (score 6):

> How come in Ruby it's possible to directly have an if statement directly in the class declaration

Because it's *not* a class "declaration", it's a class *body*, i.e. it's executable code just like a method body, a block body, a loop body or a script body.

Answer (score 2):

Without any problem. Class declaration code normally gets executed, with self = class itself, no problem defining local variables such as foo. Just remember that you are not in the class instance, but in the class itself.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  foo = true
  if foo
    bar = "x"
  end
  puts bar
end
```

Should print "x"