# page object gem - when are the required methods generated?

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I believe that when using page-object gem, having a method call like

```
link(:sym, text: "example.com")
```

generates three methods - `sym`, `sym_element` and `sym?` 
Can anybody clear the following doubts?

1. When exactly are these methods created i.e., when does the page-object class uses `define_method` to implement these methods?
2. These method calls (`link(:sym, text: "example.com"`) are present directly inside the class without being wrapped inside another method!! Is it allowed to have statements directly inside a class without being wrapped in a method? If so, what is the use of those statements?

   ```
   class Test
     include PageObject

     def example_method        
       puts "example method"    
     end

     link(:sym, text: "example.com")        
   end
   ```
3. Can I call (`link(:sym, text: "example.com"`) inside a method present in my class. Doing it this way throws a `NoMethodError`!! Is this not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quesiton 1. When exactly are these methods created**

The methods (eg `link`) are executed when the class block is evaluated.

For example, you can create a file with just the following code, which is just the definition of a page object class. If you execute it, you will see that the `sym` method exists immediately after the `link` method is called.

```
require 'page-object'
class Test
    include PageObject

    # The link method has not yet been called so sym will not exist yet
    puts Test.method_defined?(:sym)
    #=> false

    link(:sym, text: "example.com")

    # Since link has executed the define_methods, sym now exists
    puts Test.method_defined?(:sym)
    #=> true
end
```

**Question 2: Is it allowed to have statements directly inside a class without being wrapped in a method**

Yes, method calls can be done directly within the class body.

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344797/ruby-method-calls-declared-in-class-body) explains it nicely:

> The body of a class definition is an execution context for code just
>   like any other. Code there is executed within the context of the class
>   (meaning self is the class object, which is an instance of Class). You
>   can have locals and instance variables (which will belong to the class
>   object itself rather than instances of the class) and you can call any
>   method that class object responds to. The code is run once the class
>   definition block is finished.

Not sure what you mean by what is the use of the statements. But, in this case, having methods like `link` help create the methods of your page object. It allows you to specify parameters that result in consistent methods across each of your page objects.

**Question 3: Can I call link inside a method present in my class**

Yes, you can call the `link` method from another method. However, the link method is a **class method**. Therefore, you can only call it like you would another class method.

The following shows calling the link method using a class method as well as an instance method.

```
require 'page-object'
require 'watir-webdriver'

class Test
    include PageObject

    def create_method_from_instance()
        self.class.link(:sym_instance, text: "example.com")
    end

    def self.create_method_from_class()
        link(:sym_class, text: "example.com")
    end
end

# link can be called using class methods
puts Test.method_defined?(:sym_class)  #=> false
Test.create_method_from_class
puts Test.method_defined?(:sym_class)  #=> true

# link can be called using instance methods
b = Watir::Browser.new
page = Test.new(b)
puts page.methods.include?(:sym_instance)  #=> false
page.create_method_from_instance
puts page.methods.include?(:sym_instance) #=> true
```

Comment: Awesome explanation!! Thanks for the examples for each case