# Define method calls for class declarations, a la Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I'm building a domain-specific hierarchical inheritance structure similar to ActiveRecord, i.e. I have a `Base` class, and then `n` children classes declared under `Base`.

I'm currently declaring specifics in the children as constants, and then calling those from the shared methods in the `Base` class, but it's getting unwieldy. I would like to implement the Rails style of declaring **class-specific, instantiated values** via method calls.

If you're familiar Rails, I'm essentially trying to duplicate the generic structure of `has_many`/`belongs_to` from ActiveRecord, or `before_action` from ActionPack.

A simplistic, contrived example of what I'm trying to accomplish...

```
class Widget < Base

  important_value :foo, :bar

end

widget = Widget.new
widget.foo
# => :bar
```

If someone can explain to me what to put in class `Base` to achieve the above, I'll be well on my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Base 
  class << self
    def important_value(key, value)
      # define method named `key` which returns `value`
      define_method(key) { value } 
    end 
  end 
end 

class Widget < Base 
  important_value :foo, :bar 
end 

Widget.new.foo # => :bar
```

Or, if the number of "important value" methods are small and known beforehand:

```
class Base 
  def foo 
    self.class.foo 
  end 

  class << self
    attr_reader :foo 

    def important_value(key, value)
      self.instance_variable_set(:"@#{key}", value)
    end 
  end 
end 

class Widget < Base 
  important_value :foo, :bar 
end 

Widget.new.foo # => :bar
```

Comment: So it's really as simple as calling class methods inside the declaration? I expected more reflection to be required, but looking at this and how much sense it makes, I'm honestly not sure why...

Comment: Stumbled across a similar question with several helpful answers -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344797/ruby-method-calls-declared-in-class-body?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't precisely match the conditions of my original question, but it was extremely helpful in moving me along.

```
class Base

  # defining variables happens at the class level
  # the first line allows us to set a sane default (skip for a nil value)
  # the second line makes the method a getter as well as a setter (this is required)
  def self.title(val = nil)
    @title ||= 'DEFAULT TITLE'
    return @title if val.nil?
    @title = val.upcase
  end

  # the instance-level reader
  # if you want to change the values from the child, use attr_accessor
  # in either case, the visibility of @title in the child is unchanged (we assume its not accessed directly)
  attr_reader :title

  # set the instance variable when the class is instantiated
  def initialize
    instance_variable_set("@title", self.class.title)
  end

end

class Foo < Base
  title "foo title"
end

class Bar < Base
  # if left commented out, the value will be set to 'DEFAULT TITLE'
  # title "BAR TITLE" 
end

f = Foo.new
f.title
# => "FOO TITLE"

b = Bar.new
b.title
# => "DEFAULT TITLE"
```